# Comparing SQLite databases on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my application I have an existing SQLite database attached. On start it's copied to phone and then being used. I know how to check if this database is already copied, but I want to check if database on the phone is the same as stored in APK. Is there any way to compare them? I want to do that programmatically.

Original database is stored in `assets` folder.

Comment: try compare the file size in bytes ?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. How can I get sizes of these files? Original is in `assets` folder in my APK, and copied is in `/data/data/my.package/databases/`.

Comment: for assert db: `context.getAssets().open("assert_db").available();` and `new File("/data/...").length();` for the actually db.

Comment: ye, the `available` sometimes has some problem, so you can read full content to memory, you can get the bytes size, or you can save the size with `hardcode`. maybe the hardcode is not a good idea, it depend on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rooted Phone then you can Watch the Details of It. but if your phone is not rooted then you are won't be able to see it.

Another thing if you have copied the Application in your Phone then it will definitely work.

So **Conclusion** is that If you have a Rooted Phone then you will be able to See and Compare, if possible try to compare its size or Time on which it is Installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have attach a DataBase with your APK and you successfully copied to your phone that exactly means that you have your old data base copied.So i think no need to compare.If you want to compare then compare all record in Table.

Second if you want to remember that your data base is already copied then use one flag in share preferences.Save true once copied.Then check its value

**Updated**

To listing all Table

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'
```

If both data base have same table then compare record of these corresponding Table

Comment: Original database contents are going to change, but it wouldn't replace the old one on phone because it is already there. That's why I'm trying to find a way to compare them.

Comment: It will not replace then you can compare Total Table if both have same number Table then compare records that's the way to do it

Comment: I'm not sure how to open database in my APK.

Comment: But your question state that you copied it. and just want to compare both data base.