# How to compare two .db files format in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm making an app for android that allows the user to backup .db files into his device. These .db files are database from my app generated by sqlite. When the user recover these files I would like to check if he didn't edited it and it still in my app database format (like created by the code below). For clarifications, please comment.

```
String SQL_CREATE_FLIGHT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + flightsEntery.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_mat + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_ori + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_des + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_data + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_mil + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Npou + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_IFRapp + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Func + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_OBS + " TEXT, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hdec + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hpou + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hsol + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hhora + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hdiu + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hnot + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hifr + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hvfr + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hnav + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Sobcapota + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00', "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hcorte + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Hacc + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_VooPara + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_VooReb + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_Trab + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_OrdyData + " INTERGER NOT NULL, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_CivF + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_CivD + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + flightsEntery.COLUMN_DiB + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
```

I would be pleasure to try any idea, thanks!

PS.: I don't want to compare if the database are equal in every detail, I just wanna to know if the columns are the same.

Comment: Duplicate of [Comparing SQLite databases on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039907/comparing-sqlite-databases-on-android)

Comment: I don't want to compare if the database are equal in every detail, I just wanna to know if the columns are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you could utilise the following which takes two Files and compares the schema (sqlite_master) between the two based upon a query which makes a union between the two groups by the name, type and sql columns (if they are the same then there would be 2 per group) and outputs those for which there are NOT 2 rows (i.e. a mismatch). If the returned Cursor has no rows then the Schema match.

```
public class CompareDBSchemas {

    public static boolean areDBSchemasEqual(File db1File, File db2File, boolean compareSizes) {
        boolean rv = true;
        if (!(db1File.exists() && db2File.exists())) return false;
        if (compareSizes) {
            if (db1File.length() != db2File.length()) return false;
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db1File.getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db1.execSQL("ATTACH '" +
                    db2File.getPath() +  "' AS other");

        /*
            WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM main.sqlite_master UNION ALL SELECT * FROM other.sqlite_master)
            SELECT * FROM cte GROUP BY type,name,sql HAVING count() <> 2
         */
        Cursor csr = db1.rawQuery("WITH cte AS (" +
                "SELECT * FROM main.sqlite_master UNION ALL SELECT * FROM other.sqlite_master"  +
                        ") " +
                        "SELECT * FROM cte GROUP BY type,name,sql HAVING count() <> 2 ",
                null
        );
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
            rv = false;
        }
        csr.close();
        db1.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public static boolean areDBSchemasEqual(File db1File, File db2File) {
        return areDBSchemasEqual(db1File,db2File,false);
    }
}
```

- Note that the above has the option to detect database size differences, which may detect changed data rather than just a schema change.

## Example Usage

The following demonstrates the above being used where 3 databases are created the first and second having the same schema, the third being different (extra column added).

### DatabseHlpr.java

```
public class DatabaseHlpr extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_COMMON = "common";
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_SCHEMA1ONLY = "schema1only";

    private int mSchema;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DatabaseHlpr(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, int schema) {
        super(context, name, null,1);
        this.mSchema = schema;
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        switch (mSchema) {
            case 1:
                useSchema1(db);
                break;
            default:
                useSchema0(db);
        }
    }

    private void useSchema1(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                MYTABLE_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                MYTABLE_COL_COMMON + " TEXT, " +
                MYTABLE_COL_SCHEMA1ONLY + " TEXT " +
                ")");
    }

    private void useSchema0(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                MYTABLE_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                MYTABLE_COL_COMMON + " TEXT" +
                ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String DB1NAME = "db1", DB2NAME = "db2", DB3NAME = "db3";
    DatabaseHlpr mDB1Hlpr, mDB2Hlpr, mDB3Hlpr;
    File db1File, db2File,db3File;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDB1Hlpr = new DatabaseHlpr(this,DB1NAME,0);
        mDB2Hlpr = new DatabaseHlpr(this,DB2NAME,0);
        mDB3Hlpr = new DatabaseHlpr(this,DB3NAME,1);
        mDB1Hlpr.close();
        mDB2Hlpr.close();
        mDB3Hlpr.close();
        db1File = new File(this.getDatabasePath(DB1NAME).getPath());
        db2File = new File(this.getDatabasePath(DB2NAME).getPath());
        db3File = new File(this.getDatabasePath(DB3NAME).getPath());
        String result = " the same ";
        if (!CompareDBSchemas.areDBSchemasEqual(db1File,db2File,false)) {
            result = " NOT the same ";
        }
        Log.d("RESULTINFO",
                "Database Schemas are " + result +
                        " for " +
                        "\n\t" +db1File.getPath() +
                        "\n and \n\t" + db2File.getPath()
        );

        result = " the same ";
        if (!CompareDBSchemas.areDBSchemasEqual(db1File,db3File)) {
            result = " NOT the same ";
        }

        Log.d("RESULTINFO",
                "Database Schemas are " + result +
                        " for " +
                        "\n\t" +db1File.getPath() +
                        "\n and \n\t" + db3File.getPath()
        );
    }
}
```

- Note that the above has been written to demonstrate the comparison process and thus File retrieval is simple and convenient. It is not intended to reflect how the files would be retrieved.

## Result :-

```
2019-10-27 07:19:23.688 28976-28976/aso.so58566618dbcompareschema D/RESULTINFO: Database Schemas are  the same  for 
        /data/user/0/aso.so58566618dbcompareschema/databases/db1
     and 
        /data/user/0/aso.so58566618dbcompareschema/databases/db2
2019-10-27 07:19:23.693 28976-28976/aso.so58566618dbcompareschema D/RESULTINFO: Database Schemas are  NOT the same  for 
        /data/user/0/aso.so58566618dbcompareschema/databases/db1
     and 
        /data/user/0/aso.so58566618dbcompareschema/databases/db3
```

## ADDITIONAL

If you wanted the ability to check row counts (data inserted or deleted) and the actual data (data changed by update) then the following adaption of the CompareDBSchemas class could be used :-

```
public class CompareDBSchemas {

    private static final String
            SQLITE_MASTER = "sqlite_master",
            SQLITE_MASTER_TYPE_COLUMN = "type",
            SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN = "name",
            SQLITE_MASTER_SQL_COLUMN = "sql",
            SQLITE_MASTER_TABLE_TYPE = "table",
            SQLITE_SYSTEMTABLES = "sqlite_",
            ANDROID_METADATA = "android_metadata",
            CTE_NAME = "cte", MAIN_SCHEMA = "main", OTHER_SCHEMA = "other"
    ;

    public static boolean areDBSchemasEqual(File db1File, File db2File, boolean compareSizes, boolean compareRowCounts, boolean compareData) {
        boolean rv = true;
        if (!(db1File.exists() && db2File.exists())) return false;
        if (compareSizes) {
            if (db1File.length() != db2File.length()) return false;
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db1File.getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db1.beginTransaction();
        db1.execSQL("ATTACH '" +
                    db2File.getPath() +  "' AS " + OTHER_SCHEMA);

        /*
            WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM sqlite_master UNION ALL SELECT * FROM sqlite_master)
            SELECT * FROM cte GROUP BY type,name,sql HAVING count() <> 2
         */
        Cursor csr = db1.rawQuery("WITH " + CTE_NAME + " AS (" +
                "SELECT * FROM " + MAIN_SCHEMA + "." + SQLITE_MASTER +
                        " UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT * FROM " + OTHER_SCHEMA + "." + SQLITE_MASTER  +
                        ") " +
                        "SELECT * FROM " + CTE_NAME +
                        " GROUP BY " +
                        SQLITE_MASTER_TYPE_COLUMN + "," +
                        SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN + "," +
                        SQLITE_MASTER_SQL_COLUMN +
                        " HAVING count() <> 2 ",
                null
        );
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
            rv = false;
        }
        if (compareRowCounts && rv) {
            csr = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM main." + SQLITE_MASTER +
                    " WHERE " + SQLITE_MASTER_TYPE_COLUMN +
                    " = '" + SQLITE_MASTER_TABLE_TYPE +
                    "' AND (" + SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN +
                    " NOT LIKE '" + SQLITE_SYSTEMTABLES +
                    "%' AND " + SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN +
                    " <> '" + ANDROID_METADATA + "')",null);
            while(csr.moveToNext()) {
                if (
                        DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db1,MAIN_SCHEMA +"." + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN))) ==
                                DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db1,OTHER_SCHEMA + "." + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN)))
                ) continue;
                rv = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (compareData && rv) {
            csr.moveToPosition(-1);
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                if (
                        isTableDataTheSame(db1,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN)))
                ) continue;
                rv = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        db1.endTransaction();
        csr.close();
        db1.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private static boolean isTableDataTheSame(SQLiteDatabase db, String table) {
        boolean rv = true;
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info("+ table +")",null);
        StringBuilder columnConcat = new StringBuilder();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            if (columnConcat.length() > 0) columnConcat.append("||");
            columnConcat.append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_NAME_COLUMN)));
        }
        csr = db.rawQuery("WITH " + CTE_NAME +
                        " AS (" +
                        " SELECT " + columnConcat.toString() +
                        " AS comparison FROM " + MAIN_SCHEMA + "." + table +
                        " UNION ALL SELECT " + columnConcat.toString() + " FROM " + OTHER_SCHEMA + "." + table +
                        ") SELECT * FROM " + CTE_NAME +
                        " GROUP BY comparison HAVING count() <> 2",
                null
        );
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
            rv = false;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public static boolean areDBSchemasEqual(File db1File, File db2File) {
        return areDBSchemasEqual(db1File,db2File,false,false,false);
    }
}
```